# Running several physics worlds on Node.js, not getting most out of server

Tags: javascript, node.js, p2, cannon.js

I'm hosting my own multiplayer game worlds on AWS using Node. The game is physics-based (using p2.js), so I have a pretty high physics step rate of 200 steps per second.

Each game has its own world, and each world needs to step every 5ms. Each game only has about 6-8 players in it, so I'm only able to host about 60 players on a server at a time. I would like to improve this, but I'm not sure how.

Right now, I'm using [nanotimer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanotimer) `setInterval` and stepping through each physics world sequentially.

```
const stepsPerSecond = 200;
// Number of games the server can manage.
const numSlots = 10;
// Evaluates to 500 microseconds (.5ms)
const timePerStep = parseInt(1000 * (1000 / stepsPerSecond) / numSlots);
const timeLabel = `${timePerStep}u`;

this.timer.setInterval(() => {
  const slotIndex = this.currIndex++;
  // Go back to beginning of slots if end.
  if (this.currIndex == this.numSlots) {
    this.currIndex = 0;
  }
  const game = this.slots[slotIndex];
  game.physics.update();
}, '', timePerStep);
```

This actually works well, as physics is generally very smooth, but the issue is that when it gets towards capacity, there are lots of stutters from what I imagine is too much computation in the thread.

Each world step takes, on average, about .2ms, and with 200 steps per second, or 5ms between each step, there is theoretically room for 25 games.

Is there a better way to do this? I feel like I'm not using the full potential of my servers. Perhaps spinning up child processes? I've tried running a second server alongside this one on the same machine, but they end up clobbering each other and making all worlds extremely laggy.

Edit: Adding a few more details about the physics world:
Each world has about 60 bodies, most of which are static walls. There are 7 moving bodies generally, with a couple of sensors for detecting "goals".

Physics world params:

```
world.setGlobalStiffness(1e8);
// Default is 4, but the puck sometimes warps through the sticks
// with this any lower, even with CCD enabled.
world.setGlobalRelaxation(10);

maxSubSteps = 4;
```

Comment: Node.js excel's at asynchronous operations,.  But physics by nature is really not async in nature.  What I would do is put your physics calculation into another process.  You could maybe try -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/thread   Actually avoid that npm, not been updated for a while now..  There is one I've used recently worked really well..  I'll just go an find it..

Comment: I see, are you suggesting each world in its own process, then send a message from the timer to compute?

Comment: Not sure what package I used now!!,  I think it might have been this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-threads-pool , or I might have even gone directly to node.js worker threads https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html  . But there was something in node where I was having to do some heavy calculations and I did this. :)   You could do each world in a own process yes,  keeps things nice and simple that way..  And then this leave your main node.js process doing what it's good at.

Comment: Could you add the performance related settings you’ve made on p2, regarding time stepping, solver, broadphase etc? And how many bodies/shapes, and what types?

Comment: @schteppe sure, just added those above.

Answer (score 0):

To get more out of p2.js, you should look through the docs and turn off things that you don’t need. For example:

```
world.defaultContactMaterial.friction=0; // if you don’t need contact friction on a ContactMaterial
world.narrowphase.enableFriction=false; // if you never need friction for anything in your World
world.applySpringForces=false; //if you don’t use springs
world.applyGravity=false; // if you don’t need gravity along x or y axis 
world.applyDamping=false; // not sure if you need this?
world.islandSplit=false; // since you have a top-down type of game with few contacts, this might save you a run of the UnionFind algorithm
world.emitImpactEvent=false; // unless you use it
world.broadphase.sortAxis=0; // 0 means x and 1 means y. Choose the axis on which your bodies are more spread out along.
world.solver.iterations=3; // this is default 10, you might want to decrease it. Just check if your collisions work OK after you change it.
```

If you want to get the most out of your servers, you should also consider the tech stack that you use. Node.js running a JavaScript physics engine will use a lot of RAM and waste CPU cycles on garbage collection. If you, for example, would switch to Box2d in C/C++, and maybe use libuv directly instead of using Node.js, you could increase performance by a good factor.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try later tonight. Thanks for your help, and thanks for a great engine! I would like to avoid using Box2d but I guess we'll see.